# What MongoDB user privileges do I need to add a user to a new/another mongo database?

Tags: security, mongodb, privileges, access-control

I have enabled authentication in the MongoDB config file after adding one admin user with the following privileges: `userAdmin` and `userAdminAnyDatabase`.

Now I connect with this user to the db where this admin user is defined (otherwise I get `exception: login failed`).

After I have successfully connected I want to add the a new user to a new database. For that I am trying:

```
use another
db.addUser(...)
```

but I get an error:

```
Wed Dec 11 17:45:18.277 couldn't add user: not authorized for insert on app.system.users at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128
```

How can I create a new database and add a first user to it?

---

**Detailed** (all users have 1234 as password in this example)

```
$ mongo mono -u admin_all -p 1234
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: mono
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52a9831de41eb640bb0f5f64"), "user" : "admin_all", "pwd" : "a6316ed4886c10663cce46bc216ea375", "roles" : [  "userAdmin",  "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52a98404ef1f9bc934b62e11"), "user" : "admin_one", "pwd" : "884f516cf308a4c6a75bbc5a0a00807b", "roles" : [  "userAdmin" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52a98415ef1f9bc934b62e12"), "user" : "admin_any", "pwd" : "1616611df9b47c58b607054d384cab99", "roles" : [  "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] }
> use another
switched to db another
> db.addUser({ user: "user", pwd: "1234", roles: ["read"] })
{
    "user" : "user",
    "pwd" : "461d4f349d8d4ec3d22a4c945010c330",
    "roles" : [
        "read"
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("52a985372fcdbfd033003a7e")
}
Thu Dec 12 10:43:19.091 couldn't add user: not authorized for insert on another.system.users at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128
```

Comment: Can you perform provide the admin db system.users record and the actual command used for the database addUser? Please change the passwords on this. The procedure you are following should work if the syntax is correct.

Comment: @JamesWahlin I have added the verbose output I get. I have also reported this [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12062)

Comment: what if ou directly log in to "db.another" like :  mongo another -u admin_all -p 123 and then try to addUser ?

Comment: Does not work. But just found the solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The mistake made was that I was using an `userAdminAnyDatabase` user that was **NOT** in the **admin** database (see [this note](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#any-database-roles)). So there **MUST** be a database called **admin** on your server! As the documentation says for the "AnyDatabase" privileges:

> If you add any of these roles to a user privilege document outside of the admin database, the privilege will have no effect.

So you must:

- add a `userAdminAnyDatabase` to the **`admin`** db

  ```
  $ mongo admin
  > db.createUser({ user: "myadmin", pwd: "1234", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase"] })
  ```
- turn on authentication

  ```
  auth = true
  setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
  ```
- connect using the new `myadmin` user to any database you want and add further users:

  ```
  $ mongo another -u myadmin -p 1234
  > db.createUser({ user: "user", pwd: "1234", roles: ["readWrite"] })
  ```

  or

  ```
  > use another
  > db.createUser({ user: "user", pwd: "1234", roles: ["readWrite"] })
  ```

Comment: I was struggling with this for a while. Eventually I ended up using MongoChef. First off I disabled auth in the mongo config. Then I connected to my Amazon EC2 instance's Mongo DB creating an SSH tunnel with MongoChef. From there I setup the permissions, restarted mongo and boom everything worked. I was even able to export my local collections into the remote instance.

Comment: great! BTW, I did not need to do step 2

Comment: now returns WARNING: The 'addUser' shell helper is DEPRECATED. Please use 'createUser' instead

Comment: where do I set enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0 ? is it in the config file?

Comment: How do I do this in mongo in kubernetes with the community controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for creating a user `prod` who connects to database `prod` assuming I had an admin user (called `admin`) already in the MongoDB:

```
> mongo admin --username root --password <pwd>
> use prod
> db.createUser(
  {
    user: "prod",
    pwd: "<pwd>",
    roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "prod" } ]
  }
)
> exit
```

After this you can login with the new user `prod` like this:

```
> mongo prod  --username prod --password <pwd>
```