# How to create a database admin that will manage its database users

Tags: mongodb, administrator, user-management

I'm using MongoDB ver2.6.2 and want to create a database admin that will able to manage its users (add and remove them). I have two databases - admin and books. The user admin_books is supposed to be a dbOwner and be able to create and remove users from books database:

```
/* creating admin db */
> use admin;
switched to db admin
> db.createUser( { "user" : "admin_root", "pwd": "pass", "roles" : ["root"] } )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "admin_root", "roles" : [ "root" ] }

/* creating books db */
> use books;
switched to db books
> db.createUser( { "user" : "admin_books", "pwd": "pass", "roles" : ["dbOwner"] } )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "admin_books", "roles" : [ "dbOwner" ] }
> db.createUser( { "user" : "logger", "pwd": "pass", "roles" : ["readWrite"] } )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "logger", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }
```

I found that all users are actually stored in admin db starting from version 2.6.
When I try to query db users when logging in to books db as admin_books I'm getting the following error:

```
> use books
switched to db books
> db.auth("admin_books", "pass")
1
> db.system.users.find()
error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on books.system.users", "code" : 13 }
```

Is there any roles and privileges I need to add to admin_books to allow him to manage users?
Or what would be the correct way of doing this?

I know there was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525103/what-mongodb-user-privileges-do-i-need-to-add-a-user-to-a-new-another-mongo-data?rq=1), but the answer suggests to add a 'userAdminAnyDatabase' privilege to user even though the admin has to manage only single db.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community for programmers. Your question, however, is a question for database administrators. I nominated this question for migration to dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The db.system.users collection is no longer used for user management - it was deprecated in version 2.6 of MongoDB:

> **system.users Privilege Documents**
>
> Deprecated since version 2.6: MongoDB 2.6 introduced a new model for
>   user credentials and privileges and no longer uses privilege
>   documents.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-documents/

As of version 2.6 all the user access information is stored in the admin.system.users collection:

> **system.users Collection**
>
> Changed in version 2.6.
>
> The system.users collection in the admin database stores user
>   authentication and authorization information.

So the way to test if a user has the privilege to add other users is not to query the system.users collection in that database. Instead, you should log in as that user and run one of the user or role management commands:

**User Management Commands**

- createUser   Creates a new user.
- updateUser   Updates a user’s data.
- dropUser     Removes a single user.
- dropAllUsersFromDatabase     Deletes all users associated with a
  database.
- grantRolesToUser     Grants a role and its privileges to a user.
- revokeRolesFromUser  Removes a role from a user.
- usersInfo    Returns information about the specified users.

**Role Management Commands**

- createRole   Creates a role and specifies its privileges.
- updateRole  Updates a user-defined role.
- dropRole     Deletes the user-defined role.
- dropAllRolesFromDatabase     Deletes all user-defined roles from a
  database.
- grantPrivilegesToRole    Assigns privileges to a user-defined role.
- revokePrivilegesFromRole     Removes the specified privileges from a
  user-defined role.
- grantRolesToRole   Specifies roles from which a user-defined role
  inherits privileges.
- revokeRolesFromRole  Removes specified inherited roles from a
  user-defined role.
- rolesInfo   Returns information for the specified role or roles.
- invalidateUserCache  Flushes the in-memory cache of user information,
  including credentials and roles.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/#user-management-commands

Comment: Thanks again, I think I need to learn how to read documentation thoroughly

Comment: Don't blame yourself, the change in going to version 2.6 was not explained very well. Some of the documentation still has ambiguous references to system.users, when it should always be admin.system.users

Comment: I still can't figure out how to create dbAdmin user with read write access on a database.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this was answered straighforwardly enough but here's how you do it:

```
db.createUser({user: "USERNAME", pwd: "PASSWORD", roles: [{role: "dbOwner", db: "DATABASE"}]});
```

Where USERNAME, PASSWORD, and DATABASE are to be filled in with your fields.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/