# Cannot log into my remote mongoDB, Modulus, Maven project

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, connection, database

I am building a practice project and trying to connect to the MongoDB on the remote server host by Modulus. I try to connect with the following code with correct username and password but still cannot log into the database. Would you please provide some advice.

The following is my connection code -
    /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("jello.modulusmongo.net", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("b9ybeDiw");
boolean auth = db.authenticate("root", "password".toCharArray());

if (auth) {
    System.out.println("Login Successful!");
} else {
    System.out.println("login Failed");
```

The following is the error message-

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for insert on b9ybeDiw.user
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:100)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:142)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:183)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
at yuyang.mongo.App.main(App.java:52)
```

Comment: Your exception says "not authorized for insert" - are you sure you have the right login and password?

Comment: Hi Krease, I am sure I have the correct username and password. I try to build the connection like this, and try to insert something afterward. But it does not work.

Comment: it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525103/what-mongodb-user-privileges-do-i-need-to-add-a-user-to-a-new-another-mongo-data

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_java.htm

Comment: Hi Sitansu, Thank you for sharing the introduction, I am reading the tutorial and trying to fix it.